# How to process textual attachments before display in Gnus?

Tags: emacs, gnus

I read my mail at work with Gnus, and I occasionally get iCalendar attachments that are hard to read in raw form.  I figured I could write a little viewer program for such attachments that would extract out the useful information and show it in place of the raw attachment body.

Since I've never before tried tweaking my mailcap settings using Gnus, I started with a simple test.  I created a file `~/.mailcap` containing this line:

```
text/calendar ; tr A-Z a-z < %s ; copiousoutput
```

Then I ran `mailcap-parse-mailcaps` to read in the change.  But when I display a message with a `text/calendar` attachment, I continue to see the attachment as I did before--that is, still containing plenty of uppercase letters that should have been downcased by my viewer command.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Did you M-x mailcap-parse-mailcaps after altering the .mailcap file?

The information on this page may be of some help to you in a more general way: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MimeTypesWithGnus